# Access SQL: How to select dates after today if current year, else select all dates

Tags: database, vba, date, ms-access

Im working on a query where if the records in a table are from the current year, i need only to select records whose day and month are equal or greater than the current date. Otherwise (if the year is greater) I need to select all dates.

I was thinking of using the iif function or conditions on the where clause but im not close at at all.

For example

```
SELECT IFF(YEAR(FECHAPAGO) = YEAR(DATE()), MONTO WHERE MONTH(FECHAPAGO) >= MONTH(DATE), MONTO) FROM CUPONES
```

or

```
SELECT MONTO FROM CUPONES WHERE IF YEAR(FECHAPAGO) = YEAR(DATE()) ...
```

I apologize if im not being clear enough but im having trouble putting it to words. If any clarification is needed Ill be happy to rephrase my question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with straight logic;

```
    select monto from cupones where (year(fechapago) = year(date() and (month(fechapago) > month(date()) or (month(fechapago) == month(date() and day(fechapago) > day(date()))( or (year(fechapago()) > year(date()))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked it a bit to work within VBA but more importantly is Im understanding the logic behind. Ill test it out further. Thanks